# Data Factory Email Errors when found on rows

Tags: azure, csv, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I'm using the Copy Data task in Data Factory to copy data from CSV files in Azure Files to a SQL Azure DB.

Within the task there is a setting called Fault tolerance which can be set to skip and log incompatible rows which writes an error log to Azure Blob Storage.

However I'd like the errors picked up from the file to be emailed to a user to action and also store the list of errors in a DB rather than a log file in blob storage.

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Comment: Hi,any progress? Does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 0):

[All features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-fault-tolerance) of Fault tolerance are established, no such email alert mechanism in that. However you could use workaround to implement your requirements.

[Blob Trigger Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-storage-blob-triggered-function#prerequisites) to monitor the blob path you configured in the fault tolerance. Once the error logs streams into your blob file, you could collect the log and use send email sdk(For example,you could just configure the output as [SendGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-sendgrid) service in MS) to the destinations you want.

As for store errors into DB,you could create another trigger function to configure the output as [Table Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table).

Just a reminder,ADF has own monitor and alert mechanism. It's for all pipelines in ADF,not specific for copy activity. You could get an idea of it from this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/create-alerts-to-proactively-monitor-your-data-factory-pipelines/).